# Animating Navigation Menu Dropdowns at the Same Time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to animate my `subnav` using `JavaScript`. I want to reveal all `subnavs`, similar to a 'mega menu' type nav. Right now, it fades in, but from the `subnav` that's furthest right, causing a gradation effect. I want them all to start at the same time.

How can I make them all animate at the same time?

See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/RzOeEX) for `HTML` and `CSS`

Here's the JS block:

```
  nav.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      const subnav = document.querySelectorAll('.subnav-block');
      subnav.forEach(sub => {
        sub.classList.add('display-block');
        setTimeout(() => {
          sub.style.opacity = 1;
        }, 100);
      });
    });

    elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      const subnav = document.querySelectorAll('.subnav-block');
      subnav.forEach(sub => {
        sub.classList.remove('display-block');
        sub.style.opacity = 0;
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with your JavaScript. All the subnavs are all animating at the same time: the issue is that they're overlapping. With your CSS as it is right now, your the first subnav is behind the other two, and the second is behind the third, like this:

[ subnav 1 [subnav 2 [subnav 3]]]

You can verify by using your browser's inspect element option.

When the second and third subnavs become transparent, you can see the first subnav behind them, so they appear darker. You need to change your CSS so that they're not overlapping.

Comment: Are you sure? I added a red border on all .subnav and it looks like they are not overlapping.

Comment: Make the borders different colors and widths for each subnav, and you'll see the problem: https://i.imgur.com/tt6iLPC.png

Comment: ahh, I see it now. On top of my head, I'm thinking of using Flexbox to position the subnavs. Do you recommend this or another method?

Comment: I think flexbox would require the .subnav-block elements to be sibling elements. Instead, I would just try and get them to be the correct width. Maybe start by adding `.nav > li { position: relative; }`.

Comment: Good point about Flexbox. `.nav > li { position: relative; }` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your hover selector as

```
.nav > li > a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
```

What this will do is to only apply hover effect on anchor tags which are direct children of li, which are direct children of element having `nav` class.